# extjs setLoading() not working from controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I have a gridview with a button in it. When the button is clicked, it calls a method from the controller. In that method, I'm trying to show a loading screen, then do some things, then hide the loading screen. Like so:

```
Ext.getCmp('center-panel').setLoading(true);        
// do something that takes a couple seconds
Ext.getCmp('center-panel').setLoading(false);
```

But the setLoading(true) does not kick in until after the method has finished running. If I comment out the setLoading(false), the loading screen will show itself, just not until after the 2 seconds, and then never go away.

Anybody know if this is possible or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong? The center-panel is defined in my Viewport like this:

```
Ext.define('HelperBatchForm.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',    
layout: 'fit',
items: [
    {
        region: 'center',
        id: 'center-panel',
        title: 'Batches',
        split: true,
        collapsible: true,
        xtype: 'batchgrid'
    }
    ,
    {
        region: 'south',
        id: 'south-panel',
        title: 'Batch Form',
        split: true, 
        //collapsible: true,            
        xtype: 'batchedit'            
    }
],

initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I couldn't find a perfect solution, but what I found out was a good workaround was

```
Ext.getCmp('center-panel').setLoading(true); 
Ext.Function.defer(function () {
    // do something that takes a couple of seconds in here
    Ext.getCmp('center-panel').setLoading(false);
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>gotta use a '#' for ids:</strike>

```
Ext.getCmp('#center-panel').setLoading(true);
```

Anyways, you don't want to call setLoading(false) right after your "something that takes a couple seconds", as it will get fired too soon.

You want to pass a callback function into whatever takes a few seconds and then call setLoading(false) from there.

Example:

```
somePanel.setLoading(true);

someStore.load({

  callback:function(){

    somePanel.setLoading(false);

  }
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason, Ext.getCmp('center-panel') does return the panel. The setLoading actually does turn on the loading mask, it just doesn't show until after the function call has finished (only if I've commented out the code that turns it off). Ext.getCmp('#center-panel') returns undefined.

Comment: I believe setLoading(false) calling too soon is not the problem either. If I remove the setLoading(false), what happens is that we get the 2 second delay, THEN we see the "Loading..." screen. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue where the code seems to be executing first, then the setLoading(true) happens even though I placed it sequentially before the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by calling the setLoading(true) in a 'beforeload' listener of the store and the setLoading(false) in a load callback. That works perfectly.

Here is an example from a view controller's perspective:

```
configureStore: function(store) {
    var me = this;
    store.on('beforeload', me.onStoreBeforeLoad, me);
    store.load({
        callback:function() {
            me.getView().setLoading(false);
        }
    });
},

onBeforeStoreLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
    this.getView().setLoading(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need show the panel/whatever before loading will work. E.g.:

```
        var pnl = Ext.create('my.WhateverPanel');
        pnl.show();
        pnl.setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(function (){
            pnl.setLoading(false);
        }
        ,3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

this.getView().setLoading('Loading module...');
setTimeout(function () {
    //process what you want to do next. For example: me.setCurrentView(id);
} , 1);